# duplicate tags [angular-ui-router] [ui-router]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

Tags [angular-ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ui-router) and [ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ui-router) both refer to the same thing, the latter being considerably newer and less used.