# Asking an [angular-ng-*] question is as easy as picking from four different tag formats

Tags: discussion, support, retag-request, burninate-request

I just noticed that the [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) tags for specific options and modules *are a mess*. While everyone was able to determine that AngularJS should be tagged with [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs), apparently nobody has decided if the other tags should include a [angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular) prefix, [angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs) prefix, or no prefix at all.

- Questions using tags prefixed with [ng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng) (with the hyphen): [2563](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-*) (20 tags)
- Questions using tags prefixed with [ng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng) (without the hyphen): [388](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngresource+OR+ngroute+OR+ngsanitize+OR+ngcloak+OR+ngmock+OR+ngmocke2e) (6 tags)
- Questions using tags prefixed with [angular-ng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ng): [73](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ng-*) (2 tags)
- Questions using tags prefixed with [angularjs-ng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng): [3323](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ng-*) (15 tags)

**I propose that we rename (or merge) the [ng-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-x) tags to match the [angularjs-ng-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-x) tags.**

---

This appears to have come up a few times, but nothing has really been done about it:

- [duplicate tags [angular-ui-router] [ui-router]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262178/duplicate-tags-angular-ui-router-ui-router)
- [Duplicate AngularJS-related tags: [angularjs-ng-*] and [ng-*]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266598/duplicate-angularjs-related-tags-angularjs-ng-and-ng)

Comment: [ngroute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngroute) => [angularjs-ng-route](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-route)

Comment: The way I see it, there should not be any synonyms, but just retags.

Comment: @Deduplicator retagging works pretty well for low-usage tags (and I'm in favor of it), but some of the main ones have _hundreds of questions_, like [tag:ng-repeat] and [tag:ngresource].

Comment: Which means a mod should do it, when there's a complete list here.

Comment: Fair enough, I can start working on a list later if someone doesn't do it first.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250923/duplicate-tags-ui-select2-and-angularjs-select2

Answer (score 6):

Here is a very rough list of the tag renames and merges that would need to happen for the AngularJS tags to be consistent across the board.

### AngularUI

- [ng-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-grid) (853) -> [angular-ui-grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ui-grid) (192)
- [angularjs-select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-select2) (83) -> [angular-ui-select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ui-select2)
- [ui-select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ui-select2) (123) -> [angular-ui-select2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ui-select2)

### AngularJS

Merge

- [ng-init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-init) (5) -> [angularjs-ng-init](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-init) (53)
- [ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-repeat) (642) -> [angularjs-ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-repeat) (2,833)
- [ng-show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-show) (168) -> [angularjs-ng-show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-show) (27)
- [ng-hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-hide) (58) -> [angularjs-ng-show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-show) (27)
- [ngresource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngresource) (216) -> [angularjs-resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-resource) (205)
- [angular-resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-resource) (321) -> [angularjs-resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-resource) (205)
- [ngroute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngroute) (143) -> [angularjs-routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-routing) (696)
- [angular-routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-routing) (318) -> [angularjs-routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-routing) (696)
- [angularjs-ng-route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-route) (50) -> [angularjs-routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-routing) (696)
- [angular-directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-directive) (178) -> [angularjs-directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-directive) (8407)
- [angular-http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-http) (139) -> [angularjs-http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-http) (108)
- [ng-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-options) (276) -> [angularjs-ng-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-options) (63)

Rename

- [ng-animate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-animate) (320) -> [angularjs-ng-animate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-animate)
- [ng-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-class) (202) -> [angularjs-ng-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-class)
- [ng-switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-switch) (77) -> [angularjs-ng-switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-switch)
- [ng-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-view) (110) -> [angularjs-ng-view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-view)
- [ng-bind-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-bind-html) (64) -> [angularjs-ng-bind-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-bind-html)
- [ng-bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-bind) (38) -> [angularjs-ng-bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-bind)
- [ng-submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-submit) (20) -> [angularjs-ng-submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-submit)
- [angular-ng-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ng-if) (77) -> [angularjs-ng-if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-if)
- [angular-ngmodel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ngmodel) (310) -> [angularjs-ng-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-model)
- [angular-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-promise) (371) -> [angularjs-promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-promise)
- [angular-filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-filters) (156) -> [angularjs-filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-filters)

Burninate

- [angular-ng-attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ng-attr) (9)
- [ng-maxlength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-maxlength) (5)
- [ngcloak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngcloak) (5)
- [ngmock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngmock) (1)
- [ngmocke2e](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngmocke2e) (3)
- [ngsanitize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngsanitize) (24)
- [ng-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-pattern) (26)
- [ng-style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-style) (24)

*See something I missed? Feel free to edit this answer.*

Comment: `ng-hide -> angular-ng-show`?

Comment: @SpencerRuport: 2+3 under point merge.

Comment: I see it. I just was curious why it's not `ng-hide -> angular-ng-hide`.

Comment: @SpencerRuport `ng-hide` is just `!ng-show`. I personally don't think they need separate tags, but I'm open for discussion on it.

Comment: `ng-hide`, as weird as it sounds, should be a synonym of `ng-show`.

Comment: There is also the tag httpBackend which is used only for angular  http://stackoverflow.com/tags/httpbackend/info. I think this one should be burninate too.