# Tags [ng-options] and [angular-ng-options] are identical

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

Ought they not to be merged? They refer to the same thing. And why does the submit-nazi script not allow me to post that as a question? There is nothing more to add to it.

Comment: We expect you to elaborate a bit which tag should be kept. And how this question extends on other clean-up requests in the android area. So the submit-nazi script did work for a bit but its message was once more ignored. Happens to the best, no worries.

Comment: My Dupe report is a dupe?!  Ah, the sweet irony! Slinks off, stage left, blushing furiously :-)

Comment: also related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283216/asking-an-angular-ng-question-is-as-easy-as-picking-from-four-different-tag

Comment: The point is that those come up often, specially in anything with  angular but I'm not sure how the community can be better engaged in actually fixing that stuff.