# Make [ng-include] a synonym of [angularjs-ng-include]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

This synonym request is just a followup of the guidelines from [Asking an [angular-ng-*] question is as easy as picking from four different tag formats](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283216/asking-an-angular-ng-question-is-as-easy-as-picking-from-four-different-tag).

- [ng-include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-include), 106 questions
- [angularjs-ng-include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ng-include), 383 questions

Comment: Can you go through these 6 posts and make sure that they are related to angularjs ng-include? (the tag they've used is angular and not angularjs). https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bng-include%5D+-%5Bangularjs%5D+is%3Aq&mixed=0. Let me know once you've checked those 6, and I'll synonymize the tags.

Comment: @BhargavRao all six checked: they are indeed related to angularjs ng-include in the sense that they are asking "_how to make that Angular1 feature work with Angular2_" kind of questions.