# Synonymize [angular-ui-router] with [angularjs-ui-router]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

The [angular-ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-ui-router) and [angularjs-ui-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ui-router) tags appear to be duplicates - the former being created over 2 years ago with over 4,000 questions and the latter being created only 5 months ago with less than 200 questions. They even both reference the same documentation in their tag wikis.

[duplicate tags [angular-ui-router] [ui-router]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262178/3123195) was a previous synonym-request for the same tag.

Comment: There's already a [synonym request](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular-ui-router/synonyms)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283216/asking-an-angular-ng-question-is-as-easy-as-picking-from-four-different-tag

Comment: Agree, and voted on request